# Creating multiple levels of json from loop

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm writing a directive in angular to help validate fields. It is working up to the point of storing the result of the validation.

I want to store it in an object like `error.password.old`

the code to do this looks like this:

```
if(!(typeof iAttrs.ngModel == "undefined"))
{
    var model = iAttrs.ngModel.split('.');
    var length = model.length;
    var target = scope.error;

    if(typeof validation[iAttrs.validate] == "function")
    {
       for(var index = 0; index < length; index++)
       {
           target = target[model[index]];
       }
       target = validation[iAttrs.validate]();
       scope.$apply();
    }
    else throw("function " + iAttrs.validate + " does not exist.");
 }
```

iAttrs.ngModel is holds "password.old".

Google is currently throwing:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'old' of undefined

This is thrown on the second iteration of the for loop.

I understand that it is undefined but i need to find a way to define it on the fly without the  normal {} notation.

Comment: this line is confusing me: `target = target[model[index]];`. You're overwriting `target` each time through the loop with a part of `target`?

Comment: I would look into the core form/ng-form/ng-model system: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form since there's already validation going on and it's certainly extensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$parse` service: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse)

http://jsfiddle.net/4LhN9/27/

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code to do that.

```
 function createObj( str ) {

            var d = str.split("."), j, o = scope.error;
            for (j = 0; j < d.length; j = j + 1) {
                o[d[j]] = o[d[j]] || {};
                o = o[d[j]];
            }
            return o;
        }

    createObj(iAttrs.ngModel);
```